# Java crashes randomly

Tags: java, windows, jvm, jvm-crash

Okay, I am facing this problem for quite a long time now and still couldn't get any solution. I will describe what's happening and what I tried to fix things.

A year back I installed intellij Idea IDE in my windows 7 32-bit (4GB ram, 3.3GHz Intel core i3 CPU). But it kept crashing and I could never launch it and build a new project. I gave up after trying thousands of times.

Few months back I installed Android Studio and the studio behaved the same. It kept crashing so frequently that I couldn't even create a single application. Sometimes I was able to build and run a project but in any case it hardly ran for no more than 7-10 minutes. I thought, again the studio uses ide of intelliJ so that might be the reason. Maybe intellij idea was too heavy to run in my system.

A month back I installed NetBeans and now, although not as frequently as above two programs, it crashes randomly. Sometimes it crashes while splash screen is loading, or when I am typing or while running apps that I create. The crashing is completely random.

I tried the following to solve the issue:

Installed windows 7 64-bit and Windows 10 64-bit assuming that there might be some OS issues (bad dll's etc.). But that changed nothing.

Extented the memory used by Java to 1024 MB's (-Xms1024m)

Tried running Java apps in linux distros (Debian and Ubuntu), they crashed.

Uninstalled and reinstalled Java 1.8 around 100 times.

Updated graphics driver.

The thing that bugs me more is that it doesn't give consistent error reports in the hs_err_pid log file. Sometimes it states that problematic frame was some java.util component and sometimes it says it was jvm.dll itself. What's more, sometimes hs_err_pid file isn't generated at all.

Please suggest me what to do in this case. This is keeping me from learning and building in Java.

Note: By crashing, I mean programs shut down completely. They don't freeze or stuck.

Thanks!

Edit: The error log file

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002823a26, pid=6768, tid=0x0000000000001578
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 550 C2 java.util.HashMap.getNode(ILjava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/HashMap$Node; (148 bytes) @ 0x0000000002823a26 [0x0000000002823660+0x3c6]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000016776000):  JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_Java, id=5496, stack(0x00000000177f0000,0x00000000178f0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000570b7e50

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000000021b, RBX=0x00000000178eb2a0, RCX=0x00000000eba21ce0, RDX=0x00000000ffffffc6
RSP=0x00000000178eb250, RBP=0x00000000178eb370, RSI=0x000000000000021b, RDI=0x0000000014544748
R8 =0x00000000eba21ce0, R9 =0x00000000eba274a0, R10=0x00000000eba24ee0, R11=0x0000000020023f5a
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000026da714, R14=0x00000000178eb298, R15=0x0000000016776000
RIP=0x0000000002823a26, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000178eb250)
0x00000000178eb250:   000000000000021b 0000000014a2b6a0
0x00000000178eb260:   0000000000000000 0000000014a2b4d0
0x00000000178eb270:   0000000000000000 00000000178eb2a0
0x00000000178eb280:   00000000178eb370 00000000026da714
0x00000000178eb290:   00000000178eb370 00000000026da7c4
0x00000000178eb2a0:   00000000178eb308 00000000025c835d
0x00000000178eb2b0:   00000000178eb318 00000000025c835d
0x00000000178eb2c0:   00000000eba274b0 00000000178eb2c8
0x00000000178eb2d0:   0000000014a2b319 00000000178eb320
0x00000000178eb2e0:   00000000eba21c80 00000000eba274a0
0x00000000178eb2f0:   0000000014a2b330 0000000000000000
0x00000000178eb300:   00000000178eb370 00000000025c81b4
0x00000000178eb310:   00000000025c835d 00000000025c81b4
0x00000000178eb320:   00000000eba274a0 00000000eba21c80
0x00000000178eb330:   00000000178eb330 0000000014a29f72
0x00000000178eb340:   00000000178eb390 0000000014a2a9f8 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000002823a26)
0x0000000002823a06:   65 ff ff ff 8b 2c 24 4c 89 0c 24 44 89 44 24 08
0x0000000002823a16:   44 89 5c 24 10 e8 80 1d de ff cc ba c6 ff ff ff
0x0000000002823a26:   8b 2d 24 44 89 54 24 08 4c 89 4c 24 10 44 89 44
0x0000000002823a36:   24 0c 66 66 90 e8 60 1d de ff cc ba f4 ff ff ff 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000000000021b is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000178eb2a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016776000
RCX=0x00000000eba21ce0 is an oop
com.sun.javafx.css.SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey 
 - klass: 'com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey'
RDX=0x00000000ffffffc6 is an unallocated location in the heap
RSP=0x00000000178eb250 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016776000
RBP=0x00000000178eb370 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016776000
RSI=0x000000000000021b is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000014544748 is pointing into metadata
R8 =0x00000000eba21ce0 is an oop
com.sun.javafx.css.SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey 
 - klass: 'com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey'
R9 =0x00000000eba274a0 is an oop
com.sun.javafx.css.SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey 
 - klass: 'com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey'
R10=0x00000000eba24ee0 is an oop
java.util.HashMap$Node 
 - klass: 'java/util/HashMap$Node'
R11=0x0000000020023f5a is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000000026da714 is at entry_point+436 in (nmethod*)0x00000000026da3d0
R14=0x00000000178eb298 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000016776000
R15=0x0000000016776000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00000000177f0000,0x00000000178f0000],  sp=0x00000000178eb250,  free space=1004k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0000000002823a26


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000016b14800 JavaThread "Thread-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6376, stack(0x0000000018f10000,0x0000000019010000)]
  0x0000000016afc800 JavaThread "JavaFX-Launcher" [_thread_blocked, id=4876, stack(0x0000000019010000,0x0000000019110000)]
=>0x0000000016776000 JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread" [_thread_in_Java, id=5496, stack(0x00000000177f0000,0x00000000178f0000)]
  0x0000000016775800 JavaThread "Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3200, stack(0x0000000017680000,0x0000000017780000)]
  0x0000000016750800 JavaThread "QuantumRenderer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6268, stack(0x0000000017290000,0x0000000017390000)]
  0x0000000016394000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5228, stack(0x0000000016890000,0x0000000016990000)]
  0x0000000016390800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6452, stack(0x0000000016790000,0x0000000016890000)]
  0x0000000014c9b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3600, stack(0x0000000016290000,0x0000000016390000)]
  0x0000000014c3d000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7144, stack(0x0000000016190000,0x0000000016290000)]
  0x0000000014c3a800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4856, stack(0x0000000016090000,0x0000000016190000)]
  0x0000000014c39800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4128, stack(0x0000000015f90000,0x0000000016090000)]
  0x00000000025b5800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6212, stack(0x0000000015e90000,0x0000000015f90000)]
  0x00000000025b0000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x0000000015d90000,0x0000000015e90000)]
  0x00000000024c0800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=5940, stack(0x0000000002290000,0x0000000002390000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000014c07000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000015c90000,0x0000000015d90000] [id=6516]
  0x00000000163b0000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000016990000,0x0000000016a90000] [id=212]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 13152K [0x00000000ead80000, 0x00000000ec280000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 80% used [0x00000000ead80000,0x00000000eba58110,0x00000000ebd80000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec000000,0x00000000ec000000,0x00000000ec280000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ebd80000,0x00000000ec000000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 0K [0x00000000c0800000, 0x00000000c3300000, 0x00000000ead80000)
  object space 44032K, 0% used [0x00000000c0800000,0x00000000c0800000,0x00000000c3300000)
 Metaspace       used 8628K, capacity 8950K, committed 9216K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 1076K, capacity 1168K, committed 1280K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011980000,0x0000000011b80000] byte_map_base: 0x000000001137c000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006541c720
 Begin Bits: [0x00000000120e0000, 0x00000000130c0000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000000130c0000, 0x00000000140a0000)

Polling page: 0x00000000001e0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2462Kb max_used=2466Kb free=243297Kb
 bounds [0x00000000025c0000, 0x0000000002830000, 0x00000000115c0000]
 total_blobs=968 nmethods=569 adapters=312
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800 nmethod 563 0x00000000028263d0 code [0x0000000002826520, 0x0000000002826630]
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800  566       3       java.util.SubList$1::next (25 bytes)
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000014c9b800 nmethod 561 0x0000000002829510 code [0x0000000002829660, 0x00000000028298d8]
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800 nmethod 566 0x0000000002828c10 code [0x0000000002828dc0, 0x00000000028292e8]
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800  567       3       com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper::get (11 bytes)
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800 nmethod 567 0x0000000002828790 code [0x0000000002828900, 0x0000000002828b28]
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800  569       3       java.net.URI$Parser::charAt (9 bytes)
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800 nmethod 569 0x0000000002828150 code [0x00000000028282c0, 0x0000000002828608]
Event: 0.593 Thread 0x0000000016390800  568       3       com.sun.javafx.css.Rule::setStylesheet (76 bytes)
Event: 0.594 Thread 0x0000000016390800 nmethod 568 0x00000000028276d0 code [0x0000000002827880, 0x0000000002827f28]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (3 events):
Event: 0.486 Thread 0x0000000016776000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002771b50 method=java.lang.String.replace(CC)Ljava/lang/String; @ 26
Event: 0.497 Thread 0x0000000016776000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000027a1b14 method=java.lang.String.indexOf([CII[CIII)I @ 134
Event: 0.573 Thread 0x0000000016776000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000027fda2c method=java.io.BufferedInputStream.read()I @ 8

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.042 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000ead87f90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims
Event: 0.215 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000eaf5fb58) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.224 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000eaf6ced8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.254 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaff7a98) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.254 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaff7ca8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.257 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaffbbb8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.257 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eaffbdc8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1390]
Event: 0.257 Thread 0x00000000024c0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000eaffc3a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1197]
Event: 0.552 Thread 0x0000000016776000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000eb8ab358) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\interpreter\linkResolver.cpp, line 1197]
Event: 0.552 Thread 0x0000000016776000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NullPointerException'> (0x00000000eb8ab358) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u131\8869\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1394]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.593 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey
Event: 0.593 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$PartitionKey done
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/Selector
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/Selector done
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/Selector
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/Selector done
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$Partition
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$Partition done
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$Slot
Event: 0.594 loading class com/sun/javafx/css/SelectorPartitioning$Slot done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7f5c70000 - 0x00007ff7f5ca7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffe97f40000 - 0x00007ffe9811b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffe97030000 - 0x00007ffe970de000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffe94560000 - 0x00007ffe947a9000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffe970e0000 - 0x00007ffe97181000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffe972a0000 - 0x00007ffe9733d000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffe96cf0000 - 0x00007ffe96d49000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffe97e10000 - 0x00007ffe97f35000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffe96d50000 - 0x00007ffe96e9a000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffe94800000 - 0x00007ffe9481e000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffe97640000 - 0x00007ffe97667000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffe95210000 - 0x00007ffe95399000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffe944c0000 - 0x00007ffe9455a000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffe953a0000 - 0x00007ffe95496000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffe8f6e0000 - 0x00007ffe8f947000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.0_none_108e4f62dfe5d999\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffe97340000 - 0x00007ffe97639000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffe94820000 - 0x00007ffe9488a000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffe97730000 - 0x00007ffe9775d000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000064b20000 - 0x0000000064bf2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000064c00000 - 0x000000006549c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffe96ce0000 - 0x00007ffe96ce8000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffe86c60000 - 0x00007ffe86c69000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffe96f60000 - 0x00007ffe96fcc000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffe92910000 - 0x00007ffe92933000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffe8d660000 - 0x00007ffe8d66a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffe928b0000 - 0x00007ffe928db000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffe947b0000 - 0x00007ffe947f9000     C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000064ad0000 - 0x0000000064adf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000064aa0000 - 0x0000000064ac9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000064a80000 - 0x0000000064a96000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffe95520000 - 0x00007ffe96957000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffe97760000 - 0x00007ffe9780a000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffe94890000 - 0x00007ffe94f82000     C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffe97820000 - 0x00007ffe97871000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffe943b0000 - 0x00007ffe943c1000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffe943f0000 - 0x00007ffe9443c000     C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffe94440000 - 0x00007ffe94455000     C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffe8c660000 - 0x00007ffe8c74f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcr120.dll
0x00007ffe82bc0000 - 0x00007ffe82c66000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\msvcp120.dll
0x0000000065970000 - 0x0000000065992000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\prism_d3d.dll
0x00007ffe82a30000 - 0x00007ffe82bb9000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d9.dll
0x00007ffe91320000 - 0x00007ffe9134a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ffe92b10000 - 0x00007ffe92ba5000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffe73430000 - 0x00007ffe74367000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\nvd3dumx.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180188000     C:\Windows\system32\nvspcap64.dll
0x00007ffe97cc0000 - 0x00007ffe97e03000     C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffe97670000 - 0x00007ffe9772f000     C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffe97880000 - 0x00007ffe97cbb000     C:\Windows\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x0000000065920000 - 0x0000000065963000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\bin\glass.dll
0x00007ffe97190000 - 0x00007ffe97298000     C:\Windows\System32\COMDLG32.dll
0x00007ffe969d0000 - 0x00007ffe96b36000     C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffe86290000 - 0x00007ffe86439000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: F:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\App\dist\run613663870\App.jar
java_class_path (initial): F:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\App\dist\run613663870\App.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Devashish Jaiswal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
USERNAME=Devashish Jaiswal
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.0)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 4161068k(2188168k free), swap 5602860k(3422252k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_131-b11), built on Mar 15 2017 01:23:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Tue Jul 11 09:28:54 2017
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Comment: I have the hs_err_pid log file generated in a random crash.

Comment: Do you have a similar problem with anything other than Java programs?

Comment: Nope. I recently worked on QT creator, Imageline's FL Studio and Photoshop too. They run fine.

Comment: Interesting... just to take a stab at it (and this is a long shot), I don't suppose ScanDisc helps?

Comment: I don't understand. What's ScanDisc?

Comment: I suppose I should call it CHKDSC now, ScanDisc is the old name - basically it checks for file corruption. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK - you can also go to File Explorer>right click on the drive where Java is installed>Properties>Tools>Check.

Comment: I am performing a disc check and will let you know what happens next in the comments.

Comment: *"I have the hs_err_pid log file generated in a random crash"* - then post it?

Comment: Do you have sample test case that can be used to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Did running CHKDSC (or hardware scans like suggested by @C.Taylor) reveal anything?

Comment: I tested my memory. There were lots of errors saying something like "unexpected behavior detected. Allocated [somevalue] at [some memory address] and found [some other value] while retrieved."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My knee-jerk reaction is to run a complete memory check with something like MemTest86. This really smells like a hardware problem.

To do so, get a blank USB stick and go over to ...

http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm

... and download the Windows image for creating a bootable USB drive. Expand the ZIP file, and use the enclosed EXE to create a bootable USB stick. Then boot the suspect system from the USB stick. It will take a few hours for the test to run.

Comment: Can you give some hints how to do that?!

Comment: Just a doubt. If it's a hardware problem, shouldn't it occur when I tried running large programs like Photoshop too? Why just Java based programs?

Comment: By doing a tiny bit of research? All the steps are given. And if one step gives you trouble use a search engine..

Answer (score 0):

Crashing thread is UI `"JavaFX Application Thread"` and crashed in native code

```
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0000000002823a26
```

Definetly there is memory corruption issue as you can see  `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)` while accessing memory location  `0x00000000570b7e50`

Kindly run the disk clean or check the bad sectors.